# capture tabpage close event

Tags: c#, asp.net

i'm using this control http://www.codeproject.com/KB/tabs/NewCustomTabControl.aspx, the one with the close red X ( like chrome ) on every tabs.
I need in my project to capture if a tab is close by the red X.. How can I do it?
Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the page to which you linked, there's a `TabClosing` event that fires when a tab is being closed.